# Joining tables (Error in SQL Syntax)

Tags: php

I wonder if someone can help spot the error for me. I'm pretty new to joining tables but I did well up to the last bit.

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(10,8)' AND d.streamitem_target IN '(10,8)') ORDER BY d.streamitem_id DE' at line 9**

```
$call="SELECT d.*, c.*, u.*
  FROM streamdata          AS d
  JOIN streamdata_comments AS c ON d.streamitem_id = c.comment_streamitem
  JOIN users               AS u ON u.id = c.comment_poster
 WHERE c.comment_poster = '$following_string'
   AND d.streamitem_id < '$lastID'
   AND (d.streamitem_target  = '$following_string' OR
       d.streamitem_creator = '$following_string')
   OR  d.streamitem_creator IN '$friendlist' 
   AND d.streamitem_target IN '$friendlist'
   ORDER BY d.streamitem_id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: It seems your quoting the IN (...) syntax: `... IN '$friendlist'`. Please past the *real* query, i.e. the parsed `$call` variable.

Comment: If `$friendlist` is a string containing parentheses, don't enclose it in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
OR  d.streamitem_creator IN '$friendlist'
```

should be

```
 OR  d.streamitem_creator IN $friendlist
```

You do not quote `IN` variables.

The same applies to the `AND d.streamitem_target IN '$friendlist'` line.

Comment: I'll remember that for the future. Works great. Thank you.

Comment: You should try and start to use [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php) in your code, it will help you parse and format parameters much easier. And MySQL_* functions are now deprecated.

Comment: I will look into your suggestion. Thank you @Matt. Will accept when it allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

I think possibly the single quotes around $friendlist in the IN clauses are your problem, eg, change to

```
   OR  d.streamitem_creator IN $friendlist 
   AND d.streamitem_target IN $friendlist
```

Answer (score 1):

You're enclosing a comma-separated list in quotes. Don't do that.

```
.
.
.
OR  d.streamitem_creator IN $friendlist
AND d.streamitem_target IN $friendlist
.
.
.
```